# Jenkins slave agent launch fails

Tags: jenkins

When launching a slave agent from a slave machine using the "Launch agent from browser on slave" option, it fails. It opens a window for slave-agent.jnlp and when opened with Java Web Start Launcher, it shows the launching application pop up and then another pop up comes with "Failed to Validate Certificate" message.

And the error details are:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
 java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.verifyResponse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSP.check(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSP.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.doOCSPEEValidation(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
    at java.security.Signature.initVerify(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Whereas when I run the "if the slave is headless:" option it opens a command prompt and shows messages of getting connected to the master. The slave also shows online on the dashboard.

The master is on my local machine, and I connect to a remote machine (Windows XP) via VPN. I want to use this remote as slave as a Windows service rather than running through a command prompt. How can I do this?

Answer (score 26):

After installing the Jenkins slave as a service, go to the configured "Remote root directory" on your slave, open the `jenkins-slave.xml` file in a text editor, add `-noCertificateCheck` to the end of the `<arguments>` tag, and restart the service. That should get rid of the certificate exception.

Comment: I tried -noCertificateCheck ...still getting error....just before slave Win-ER-OnDemand gets launched ...
executing pre-launch scripts ...
[12/29/17 11:01:16] Launching agent
$ aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-0bb13cxxxxx --region ap-southeast-1
{
    "StartingInstances": [
        {
            "PreviousState": {
                "Name": "running",
                "Code": 16
            },
            "CurrentState": {
                "Name": "running",
                "Code": 16
            },
            "InstanceId": "i-0bb13c3xxxxx"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: ERROR: Unable to launch the agent for Win-ER-OnDemand
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
 at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:411)
 at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:356)
 at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:412)
 at

Comment: hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:139)
 at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:285)
 at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Process terminated with exit code 0

Comment: Disabling certificate check is not a solution it is failure to fix problem.

Comment: That's an easy statement to make if you don't have an alternative solution to provide.

Answer (score 0):

First, from the control panel select *"Java"*. Select *"Advanced"* tab. Extend "Security". Ensure *"Enable online certificate validation"*, and *"Enable online certificate validation for publisher certificate only"* are unchecked.

Then run the JNLP file. You need to create the Jenkins root directory if it does not exist.

Finally, follow @sschuberth's answer.

Comment: tried your options also .....
Dec 29, 2017 11:22:04 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.GuiListener$2 run
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:651)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:615)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:451)