# Jenkins service starts then stops on Windows 7

Tags: jenkins

I downloaded the native windows Jenkins package and installed it. On installation, it starts as a service in and shows in Task Manager, and also on going to the url localhost:8080. But then it stops. Here is what I get in my jenkins.out.log:

```
Running from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Jenkins home directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins found at:  EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? I've checked throuh netstat that no other process is using the port 8080.

Comment: anythingthing in the Jenkins.err.log?

Comment: In my case this provided the fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/26782250/1808261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched back to version 1.535 and now it works.

Answer (score 9):

I found that the java.exe process was hung and keeping Jenkins from starting. I killed the java process and then jenkins service started up just fine.

Use process explorer.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to start jenkins via the command line using `java -jar jenkins.war`, however, because the process is started via the command line it will also end when that command window is closed.

A better way would be to start the service via `jenkins.exe` but you would have to remind doing that at every startup.

Ultimately we have settled with a batch script with the following content:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins"
start javaw -jar jenkins.war >> outputFile.txt
```

adding `start` before calling javaw makes sure that the command window is not attached to the process started, making it possible to safely close down the command line.

Using `>> outputFile.txt` writes the command window feedback in a text file, making debugging a whole lot easier when Jenkins ever breaks down!

Save it in a batch script, schedule it with windows Task Scheduler to run at startup et voilà: properly set up Jenkins service. 
Only make sure it doesn't stop at log-off.

Answer (score 0):

After my win vm system rebooted, the jenkins 1.625.2 service would just keep stopping.

It solved it by:

- Kill java processes. Found some old java running dll's.
- Uninstall old version of jdk1.6 that was there.
- Cleaning java temp. files dir.

Then I was able to restart the service w/o problem.

Answer (score 0):

if java.exe not visible in process 
 1.netstat -a -o -n  find out the PID of your port
 2.tasklist /FI “PID eq PID″
 3.taskkill /F /PID 2600 kill the process